# In R Shiny, how do I pass multiple inputs to renderDataTable?

Tags: r, shiny

How do I pass multiple inputs to renderDataTable? I can get it to work for one input, but after hours of searching cant find an example with two inputs for the one table.

With one input (working):

```
output$mytable1 = renderDataTable({data[data$plate == input$mytext,]}, )
```

I assume two inputs would look like this? but it is incorrect:

```
output$mytable1 = renderDataTable({data[data$plate == input$mytext, data[data$date == input$dateRange,]}, )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error has nothing to do with shiny or multiple inputs. You have to connect your inputs (conditions) with some logic like `OR` or `AND`. Take this example from the `mtcars` dataset: Assume you want to get 8 cylinder cars with a horsepower greater than 200

if you write like :
`mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 8, mtcars$hp > 200,]`

as in your example you get an error as R does not know what you want to do .

If you write
`mtcars[mtcars$cyl ==8 & mtcars$hp > 200,]`
you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the data with both inputs than the correct code is:

```
output$mytable1 = renderDataTable({data[data$plate == input$mytext & data[data$date == input$dateRange,]} )
```

the coma should be replaced with a logical operator (i have put &)

Comment: Thanks for your responce